# Pattern recognition in numbers?

Tags: pattern-matching, text-mining

Consider the  input file be

```
25 27 29 25 27 29 25 27 29 25 27 29 25 27 28
```

I want to extract the pattern 25 27 29. What are the algorithms that I  can use to mine the pattern in a  sequence  like this? I'm willing to implement it using unsupervised learning techniques.

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer as pattern and extracting might mean different things:

Is your `pattern` including the spaces between the numbers, or just the list of number themselves? Is the pattern exactly `25 27 29` or `n n+2 n+4`

Does `extract` mean finding the position? Removing it from the list?

Therefore, there are no algorithms or techniques as is it hard to understand what you are willing to do.

In a Python style and in a very general way (you can replace `a`, `b` and `c` with integers and make the list longer), you can go for :

```
list = [25, 27, 29, 25, 27, 29, 25, 27, 29, 25, 27, 29, 25, 27, 28]
ptn = [a, b, c]
position = []

for i, nb in enumerate(list):
    if i != len(list) - len(pattern);
         if nb == ptn[i] and list[i+1] == ptn[i+1] and list[i+2] == ptn[i+2]:
               position.append(i)
```